"Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource"
I'm building a frontend application in React (running on http://localhost:3000) that makes POST requests to a Quarkus backend API (running on http://localhost:8080). However, when I try to send a request, I get the following error:
Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

I've configured CORS in my application.yml file for Quarkus as follows:
quarkus:
  http:
    port: 8080
    cors:
      enabled: true
      origins: "http://localhost:3000"
      methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS
      headers: Content-Type,Accept,Authorization
      allow-credentials: true

Despite this, I still get the error. I understand that this is likely related to the preflight OPTIONS request, but I’m unsure what else I need to configure to make this work. I’ve also tried setting origins: "*" (for debugging), but since I have allow-credentials: true, I know I can’t use * for the origin.
The backend works fine when tested directly with curl.

The configuration looks correct, can you please check with your browser's Web developer tools what is being sent to from the browser and what is being received in response ?

Also, which Quarkus version is it ?

Due to a misconfiguration CORS filter hasn't been enabled.
During the startup the following entry should appear in the logs
2024-11-11 20:06:07,117 WARN  [io.qua.config] (Quarkus Main Thread) Unrecognized configuration key "quarkus.http.cors.enabled" was provided; it will be ignored; verify that the dependency extension for this configuration is set or that you did not make a typo

Exectuing command below, a 403 CORS Rejected - Invalid origin would be excepted.
curl -v -X OPTIONS \
   'http://localhost:8080/' \
   -H 'Origin: https://not-allowed-origin.com' \
   -H 'Access-Control-Request-Method: GET' \
   -H 'Access-Control-Request-Headers: X-Requested-With' 

The point is there is no configuration option like quarkus.http.cors.enabled=true but quarkus.http.cors=true
Because YAML format doesn't support combining scalar and object nodes, using ~ (tilde) is the key (literally).
The working YAML configuration should be like this.
quarkus:
  http:
    cors:
      ~: true
      origins: "http://localhost:3000"
      methods: GET,POST,OPTIONS
      headers: Content-Type,Accept,Authorization
      access-control-allow-credentials: true

Bonus: I replaced another bad configuration key (allow-credentials) with the good one (access-control-allow-credentials)
For further information follow these guides:
https://quarkus.io/guides/security-cors
https://quarkus.io/guides/config-yaml#configuration-property-conflicts
